# Select row in custom list view and add action bar item

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I have an android application with a custom list view. I would like to realize the following situation...

I have in my fragment view an `OnItemLongClickListener` method:

```
CustomListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e("-->", "HELLO WORLD");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If a long click will be detected, I would like to show the options to select multiple rows, - little bit like on the following screenshot:

[image]

And I also would like to make an `ActionBar` Item visible, which is hidden the whole time.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Use Two Listener, one setOnLongClicklistener, normal onItemClickListener, initially keep onItemClickListener(null). Initiate onItemClickListener inside Listview.setOnLongClikListener. Think this will do, and don't forget to keep your android:choicemode="multipechoice" in listview xml.

Answer (score 0):

for doing work with check book you have to use a flag in array list which by default should be true for every list item when you long pressed you will set falg false for all the list item and call setdatanotifychanged method of adapter and when you select each item then you should set flag value true.

**Action Bar – Hide and Show**

To hide Action Bar, invoke hide() method using getSupportActionBar( ) [getActionBar( ) in case of minSDKVersion is 11 or higher] as shown below:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
// If your minSdkVersion is 11 or higher, instead use:
//getActionBar().hide();
```

To show Action Bar, invoke show() method using getSupportActionBar( ) [getActionBar( ) in case of minSDKVersion is 11 or higher] as shown below:

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
// If your minSdkVersion is 11 or higher, instead use:
//getActionBar().show();
```